# My encryption algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

I was bored and made up an encryption algorithm using Python. I'm just curious to find out if anyone would be interested in trying to break it, or maybe point me in the right direction of a forum or website where I could test the strength of my algorithm. If you can help me with this please respond to this question. Thanks

Comment: While I can appreciate the intellectual exercise of developing your own encryption algorithm, I hope that you won't actually use this algorithm in an application.  Cryptographic algorithms and implementations are notoriously difficult to get right.

Comment: I realize that. I was just bored

Comment: You can just put your algorithm here, and rephrase your question to something like "how secure is this cipher?".

Comment: This isn't a real question.  If you rephrase it how Tomas has suggested it could be neat though.

Comment: @Tomas Actually I was hoping to test it to further develop it and maybe eventually using it in an application. Yes I realize that's a pipe dream. But who doesn't have those.

Comment: @GWW I realize it's not a real question. I'm just trying to find someone who is bored enough to test my encryption or perhaps point me in the right direction of a website that would be better

Comment: @Chris: the hard bit of crypto algorithms is the maths not the programming.

Answer (score 2):

First, read this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute_force_attack

Then follow the links.

Specifically, read this one: http://www.sciengines.com/copacobana/

Now that you've done some reading, you can download a brute-force encryption
breaker and break your code.

It's that easy.  We don't need to do it for you.  You can do it yourself.

Comment: Usually when trying to "break an encryption algorithm" you aren't really looking for brute force solutions. If the algorithm is weak enough that that's feasible, it's completely uninteresting anyhow.

Comment: @Voo: The point is that "I'm just trying to find someone who is bored enough to test my encryption" is a total waste of everyone's time if brute force works.